# VS2010 vs VS2008 SP1 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

How stable is Visual Studio 2010 compared with VS2008 SP1 on Windows 7?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So far, VS2010 is only available as an early CTP (from last November) in a VPC, so it's not really a relevant comparison.  It's for looking at, not using.

Comment: Then again, Windows 7 is also in beta, so it's a close enough comparison

Comment: Not for stability.  It's pointless to test an early beta for stability.  It's also pointless to test Windows 7 for performance or stability, for that matter.

Comment: Randolpho - it's not a close comparison at all.  Win7 Beta is a final beta shipped with the kind of quality and expectations that VS Beta 2 may have.  The CTP of VS2010 was potentially so flaky it had to ship in a VM - it was something to look at as a gift for PDC attendees.

Comment: The beta is available on MSDN now

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for VS2010 on Windows 7, but I have been using VS2008sp1 on Windows 7 as my primary development machine and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Considering I've never gotten VS2008 to crash on ANY OS, id say its hard to get any better than that.  Granted I may not have put it through its full paces, but I have hit a wide range of abilities over the past year or so since moving to VS2008

EDIT:
Nevermind I just remembered crashing it when a former coworker insisted on using Source Safe, which ran off a laggy server, the lag alone brought VS2008 down.

Comment: I crash vs2008 regularly (mainly the debugger with c++) but it has a nice autorestart feature.

Comment: You can have some of my crashes then :)

Comment: Yup, I had lots of crashes, mostly to do with silverlight designer for VS2008. It's pretty annoying, really.

Comment: I'm lucky if I don't kill it at least daily. I *occasionally* manage to get it to BSOD, which is fun.

Comment: Marc - you should probably look at your video drivers.  VS couldn't cause a BSOD if it wanted to.

Comment: VS2008 crashes on a regular basis for me, especially when I run multiple instances of it.